# Usage of have and had

Tags: grammar

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

> I have had the pleasure of meeting him.
>
> I had the pleasure of meeting him.

If both are correct, what are the exact scenarios to use them appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have had the pleasure of meeting him

means that at some, indefinite, point in the past I met him. The point being made is that he is now someone I have met, as opposed to someone I have not met. Where and how I met him is not important.

> I had the pleasure of meeting him

means that the meeting occurred  on a particular occasion to be specified in the context.

> I had the pleasure of meeting him in Llandudno
>
> I had the pleasure of meeting him at Christmas
>
> I had the pleasure of meeting him at Mark and Mary's wedding
>
> I had the pleasure of meeting him when I was a steeplejack
>
> I had the pleasure of meeting him before he got married

OR if I just want to say I've met him before

> I have met him

Answer (score 0):

The first is most likely to occur in the following conversation where a specific difference between having met and not having met is asserted.

Friend A: *I haven't had the pleasure of meeting the professor*.

Friend B: *I **have** had the pleasure of meeting him*.

In most cases simply saying *I had the pleasure of meeting him* will suffice.